# How to add two arrays in a loop with unknown length

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, merge

i have a measurement-instrument that creates measurements for a specified time. During this time i have to fetch the measurements from the internal memory to prevent an overflow.
Currently i have this:

```
public int FetchDatalog(int Time_s, double Period, out int Count, ref double[] Results)
{
    Count = 0;


    try
    {
        DateTime timeout = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(Time_s);
        double[] values;

        while (DateTime.UtcNow < timeout)
        {

        values = //here is the command to tell the instrument to return 10 results
        Count = values.Count();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        //HERE IS SOMETHING MISSING <-----
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

So i have a function that reads in a loop always 10 results from a instruments until a specified time is over. During the loops the read data must be merged.

At the arrow-marked position i need now something that merges the 10 values together and finally returns all merged values back in results.

How can i do this with unknown length?

(As extra problem is: The 10 results can be "up to 10" results. Sometimes less then 10, so i could change here also if needed to only read 1 value, but this would make it slowlier.

Thanks for all help

---

Added comment here so its readable - Sayse

I mean merge:

```
loop1: values[]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0; 
loop2: values[]=11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,11 
loop3: values[]=111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,111
```

This three values should finally return in parameter result as

```
result[]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,22,33,44,55,66,
     77,88,99,11,111,222,333,444,555,6‌​66,777,888,999,111
```

So they should be put together to a bigger array.

Comment: What do you mean by merge them?  Sum them, average them, do some other complex computation, what?

Comment: And have you considered returning a `List<double>` of the results? All this messing around with `ref` and `out` parameters is a bit odd (as are your parameter names).

Comment: Off topic note: I don't think `Thread.Sleep` is doing anything useful

Comment: Why not just declare a `List<double>` and at your arrow position, do `theList.AddRange(values);`.  Then you have all the results together once the loop ends.

Comment: I mean merge:
loop1: values[]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0;
loop2: values[]=11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,11
loop3: values[]=111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,111

This thre values should finally return in parameter result as
result[]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,11,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,111

So they should be put togehter to a bigger array.

Comment: if you want to merge to one value as an average then use average linq method

Comment: Added your comment to your question, definitely ditch the arrays and use a list.

Comment: @ThomasMann Just for clarification / future knowledge, that's called concatenation, not merging.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to maintain the array as your parameter type for some reason, you could just create a list, append to the list, then return the result:

```
public int FetchDatalog(int Time_s, double Period, out int Count, ref double[] Results)
{
    Count = 0;
    List<double> existing = new List<double>(Results);

    try
    {
        DateTime timeout = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(Time_s);
        double[] values;    
        while (DateTime.UtcNow < timeout)
        {
            values = //here is the command to tell the instrument to return 10 results
            Count += values.Length;
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            existing.AddRange(values);
        }    
    }
    finally 
    {
        Results = existing.ToArray();        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I had my druthers, it'd look more like:

```
public int FetchDatalog(int readLength, double sleepPeriod, List<double> results)
{
    var readingsCount = 0;
    try
    {
        var timeout = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(readLength);
        while (DateTime.UtcNow < timeout)
        {
            values = RetrieveBufferedSensorReadings(10);
            readingsCount += values.Length;
            results.AddRange(values);                
            Thread.Sleep(sleepPeriod);
        }
        return readingsCount;
    }
    catch (Exception e) //<-- this should be special purpose based on sleep/read failures
    {
       throw; //Return -1 or the like if you must... but ew.
    }
}
```

You could even look at using the newer `async` functionality in 4.0 as `Thread.Sleep` is generally considered bad.

**EDIT:**

Based on your last comment, it seems you are doing this:

```
double[] Results = new double[100]; 
ret = GetData(TimeSec, out Count, ref Results);
```

I feel this is poor structure, but we'll go with it as a learning tool:

```
public int GetData(int Time_s, out int Count, ref double[] Results)
{

    var lengthIncrement = 100;
    Count = 0;

    try
    {
        DateTime timeout = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(Time_s);
        double[] values;    
        while (DateTime.UtcNow < timeout)
        {
            values = //here is the command to tell the instrument to return 10 results

            //Before copying over value, make sure we won't overflow
            //If we will, extend array
            if (Count + values.Length > Results.Length) {
               var temp = new double[Results.Length + lengthIncrement];
               Array.Copy(Results, temp, Count);
               Results = temp;
            }                

            Array.Copy(values, 0, Results, Count, values.Length);
            Count += values.Length;
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

An [ideone example.](http://ideone.com/8BMY9t)

Allow me to reiterate what many other's are saying... The following is a much better design:

```
var results = new List<double>(); 
ret = GetData(TimeSec, out Count, results);
```

Comment: I would move the instantiation of `existing` before the while and set `Results` after so you dont create a new List every iteration.

Comment: Thank you for the code-sxample. It works great.
@Cemafor: Can you please describe what i have to change then? Thanks

Comment: @ThomasMann, He already added my suggestion into his code. I think the edit was soon enough where it doesnt show as an edit on the answer. Although, the try finally seams a little weird. What was the try doing in the original code?

Comment: The try in his original code wasn't doing anything... I just stole it and used the finally to ensure his return variable was updated.

Comment: I have a try &catch block in my code. I didnt insert it here to keep it small.

Comment: I tried the code but i have a problem with it.
I call the above code like this:

double[] Results = new double[100];
ret = GetData(TimeSec, out Count, ref Results);

When i set "TimeSec = 10" so to measure for 10sec abd the measurement speed to create 1 result per seconds, then the Result[]-array should return 10 values.

But currently this 10 new results are added at the end of my site-100-array. So i have 100 zeros and then the 10 results.
My idea was that the values are coming at the beginning of the array and the count-parameter should return how many of the values are measure-values .

Comment: I think you need to figure out what you want/need, then go from there.    If you want concatenation, this will do it.  If you want to keep a hard-count, you can do that as well. I'll update my answer as an example momentarily.

Comment: Ah, the count-problem is solved already in the code above.
So only the problem with the results at wrong position is left.
Thx

Comment: I posted the update which will do what you're requesting.  This has a very C-feel to it, which is very unnecessary in modern languages.

Comment: Thanks for the changes, but it still adds the new values at the end of the [100]-Array so if Coun returns with 94 then Result has size 194. First 100 elements are zero and then are the measurement-valzes coming.

Comment: Did you copy the code that was after the edit?  That should be impossible.

Comment: Sorry, i copied again everyting and it works. (Before i tried to copy only the changes.)
Thank you very much for the code.